# Xamarin.ios UISegmentedControl get ID Value on Click

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a Xamarin iOS project in which i populate a UISegmentedControl. When the data is loaded from the database, i create the control via code behind:

```
BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    UISCTypes.RemoveAllSegments();
    UISCTypes.AllEvents += UISCTypes_AllEvents;
    foreach(Type item in Types) {
       UISCTypes.InsertSegment(item.Name, item.Id, true);
    }
});
```

The problem is, when i add the segments, i want to get the ID back (item.Id) when clicked, but the following is bringing back the segment position....

```
private void UISCTypes_AllEvents(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    UISegmentedControl a = (UISegmentedControl) sender;
    int b = (int) a.SelectedSegment;
    _client.GetItemsAsync(b, Period, 1);
}
```

Is there a way i can map the item.Id to the segment position? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If `Types` collection doesn't change after data is loaded you could do `Types[a.SelectedSegment].Id`

Comment: Thanks Andrius, that will work but I was trying to find a way of almost mapping the id value with the segment position. Just to be safe.